# Solutions needed for a Java EE web project

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsp, servlets, ejb-3.0

Currently, I am working on a web project involving using java EE framework to access data generated by a legacy system backed by oracle database. The legacy system randomly updates the date a few times per hour, but the webpages have to reflect the date change promptly(within seconds). I am wondering , apart from generating frequent refresh requests updating the webpages, is there any other way I can achieve the same goal?

the project is still in a very early stage,  I am wild open for any solution.

btw, just a bit of background regarding myself, As a matter of fact, this is my first Java EE project, however, I have moderately good understanding of jsp, servlet, hibernate , spring  and ejb 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how "legacy" your legacy Oracle database is, you may be able to use the [Database Change Notification functionality](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm). Another option might be to set up JMS messaging between the database and your application.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of "push feature".

Richfaces or Icefaces Jsf libraries provide such capability.

Comment: thanks for your input, dcernahoschi.  sounds very promising to use push feature to synchronize server side with client side. but in my case, the data update originated from a legacy system,rather than the client side. so ,still I am facing a new task to synchronize the web tier with data tier, and make web tier aware of the data change instantly. currently, the only idea I have is to use spring scheduler to refresh EJB entity or Hibernate session.